# Node.js show mongodb find result on html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I've made simple node.js app to sent numbers to mongo db. Insert "batch number" or update if exist. I want to list every refresh on html page every documents with 'heat: false' in database. I'm thinking about use app.js for many different places (piec1, piec2...) and add documents into db with name of it (piec1, piec2...). How I can do it?

My index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul>
   <li><h2>PIEC</h2></li>
</ul>

<h1>Zeskanuj etykietę</h1>

<form action="/batch_save" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="batch" id="batch" autofocus="autofocus" required>
</form>

<h1>W trakcie wygrzewania:</h1
**HERE I WANT TO PLACE LIST OF heat: false documents.**

</body>
</html>
```

and app.js:

```
var express=require("express");
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://10.27.10.155:27017/heatongo');
var db=mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.log.bind(console, "connection error"));
db.once('open', function(callback){
    console.log("connection succeeded");
})

var app=express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/batch_save', function(req,res){
    var batch = req.body.batch;
    var currentdate = new Date().toLocaleString('pl-PL', {
  timeZone: 'Europe/Warsaw'
});

    var data = {
        "batch": batch,
        "heat": false,
        "timein": currentdate,
        "timeout": currentdate
    };

    var Batch = require('./model.js');

    Batch.exists({batch: batch}, function (err, ex) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
                    if (ex == null) {
                        db.collection("piec1").insertOne(data, function(err, collection){
                                if (err) throw err;
                                console.log("Record inserted successfully");
                            });
                    } else {
                        Batch.updateOne({batch: batch}, {heat: true}, function(err, update){
                            if (err) throw err;
                            console.log("Record updated seccessfully");
                        })
                        Batch.updateOne({batch: batch}, {timeout: currentdate}, function(err, update){
                            if (err) throw err;
                            console.log("Time updated seccessfully");
                        })
                }
        }
            return res.redirect('index.php');
    });
})

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.set({
    'Access-control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
return res.redirect('#');
}).listen(3000)

console.log("server listening at port 3000");
```

Comment: You can send the find method result to the html page as a response object of a request (e.g. GET method).

Comment: I'm starting with coding, could you say me how I can do this?